# ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape' from keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

In Keras,

I'm trying to import `_obtain_input_shape` as follows:

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

However, I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape'

The reason I'm trying to import _obtain_input_shape is so that I can determine the input shape(so as to load [VGG-Face](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/) as follows :

I'm using it to determine the correct input shape of the input tensor as follow:

```
input_shape = _obtain_input_shape(input_shape,
                                  default_size=224,
                                  min_size=48,
                                  data_format=K.image_data_format(),
                                  require_flatten=include_top)`
```

Please assist?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do what you're trying. What exactly is it you want to do with `_obtain_input_shape`?

Comment: Hi @DanielMöller, I have edited my question to include more information .

Comment: You know that keras doesn't have a VGG-Face, right? The input shape should be chosen by you when you create a model. If you want the default input shape, just pass `(224,224,3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Daniel, yes I know. I want to load VGG-face pre-trained weights. I will try what you suggested and let you know .

Comment: Anybody know how to import this for tensorflow.keras?

Comment: @Austin You can always go to the original code definition and copy paste the needed code into an own library. Load that library instead. The _obtain_input_shape can be found here : https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**You don't have to downgrade Keras 2.2.2.**

In `Keras 2.2.2` there is no `_obtain_input_shape` method in the `keras.applications.imagenet_utils` module. You can find it under [keras-applications](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications) with the modul name keras_applications (underscore).

So you don't have to downgrade your Keras to 2.2.0 just change:

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

to

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Comment: this should be accepted as the correct answer @Tshilidzi Mudau

Comment: @Geeocode Any idea how to import this through tensorflow.keras?

Comment: @Austin Please give me a more specific question to be able to answer.

Comment: @Geeocode can I import _obtain_input_shape from TensorFlow 1.12?

Answer (score 11):

I have found a method that works well. You just use

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Notice: It is `keras_applications` instead of `keras.application`.

Comment: I have keras 2.2.4 and after the suggested change also, I see the same problem. Any help, please.

Comment: from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape

Answer (score 7):

This issue occured because of the version of keras.

In my case, I was downgrade keras 2.2.2 to 2.2.0, and the problem was solved.

Comment: how do you upgraded kerns 2.2.2 to version less than 2.2.2

Comment: Use 'pip install keras==2.2.0'

Comment: @W.Sam you don't have to downgrade Keras, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In Colab I solved it by importing `Keras` and installing :

```
import keras
!pip install keras_applications
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Answer (score 1):

keras_applications.imagenet_utils is deprecated

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inception_v3.py", line 36, in 
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_application

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import obtain_input_shape
```

Not _obtain_input_shape. This works fine with keras==2.5.0rc0 (pip install keras==2.5.0rc0)

Answer (score 0):

for keras 2.2.4:
Change the line like below to make it work.

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Note: It is importing from **keras_applications** and does not from **keras.applications** as before.