# while import resnet got error - ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape''

Tags: keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, resnet, auto-keras

I got an while importing resnet.

I tried removed latest version and install old version of keras==1.0.6 and it doesn't work. Also i did changes in resnet.py -->  "from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape , i got an error an like "ImportError: cannot import name 'GlobalMaxPooling2D' "

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
import os
import numpy as np
from pickle import dump
import resnet
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import Model
from os import listdir
import cv2
from keras import applications
```

I need import all these without an error. kindly help me to sort this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name '\_obtain\_input\_shape' from keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113140/importerror-cannot-import-name-obtain-input-shape-from-keras)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

with

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Comment: yes , when i changed it as from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape                                                                                                                        i got an error like ImportError: cannot import name 'GlobalMaxPooling2D'
its keras.layers