# colab keras _obtain_input_shape import error

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I am executing below mentioned code on colab.

```
from tensorflow.keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

`_obtain_input_shape` was imported successfully a few days back but now it is giving me following error.

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras_applications'**

Colab is using keras version 2.4.3 and tensorflow version 2.3.0 .

So i changed the above code to

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Still i get the following error
**ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape'**

How do i get `_obtain_input_shape` without downgrading the keras and tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `keras-applications` in your system and then run

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

or

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

based on your Keras version.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113140/importerror-cannot-import-name-obtain-input-shape-from-keras)